# jQuery disable anchor tag and select child element?

Tags: jquery, select, anchor

I'm having much trouble figuring this out, so maybe someone can help me.

This is my html:

```
<p>
post content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>

<p>
post #2 content
<span><a href="#" class="voteUp">I approve this message <span>${post.upvotes}</span></a></span>
</p>
```

And my JS:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $("a span").html(data);
    });
});
```

Basically what I want to do is change the value of the inner span with the value that `data` contains. The code above does work, but it is changing the content of every span, and not only the child of the clicked anchor.

Another thing I want to do is disable the anchor tag once a vote has been submitted.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    var voteUp = $(this);
    if(voteUp.hasClass('disabled'){
        // don't do anything, because it's disabled
    } else{
        $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
            voteUp
                .addClass('disabled') // add a class, which you can check on a click event fired
                .find("span")
                .html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Didn't think of doing this with CSS. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sled: Yep, element's class can be used both for styling and logic in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".voteUp").click(function() {

        $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data) {

            $(this).children("span").html(data);

        });

        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your callback function from $.post is asynchronous, so you lose your context without proper framing.  So, this means that your `$('a span')` searches the entire DOM, hence why it was replacing everything.

**EDIT**: Alright, Shef is splitting hairs but made me realize that using unbind (or shef's method) will still not return false on the click and as such will have a nice "kick to the top" effect when you click on the `<a href="#">`.  This code has been updated to fix that.

```
$("a.voteUp").click(function(){
    //Set a local variable to the anchor that was clicked on for future use
    var $this = $(this);
    $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
        $this.find("span").html(data);

        //Unbind this "voteUp" button.  This will remove the click handler and apply a class of "disabled"
        $this.unbind('click').click(function() { return false }).addClass('disabled');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Now, in your CSS:

```
.disabled { color: #999; }
```

This will make the text in elements that are "disabled" be gray.

Comment: This will just `unbind` the click event from the `a` tag, but the `a` tag itself will still be clickable.

Comment: That's correct.  Clicking on it will do nothing, which is how I interpreted his problem.  If he wants to make it do nothing and gray it out, then he can just add the line to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Disabling the link doesn't work, but this part `$this.find("a span").html(data);` does, though without the `a` inside find(like Goblin suggested). Any idea idea about disabling the link?

Comment: How exactly do I gray it out?

Comment: Sled, I apologize--I updated my code both to fix the find, and to append a class.

Comment: @Adam Terlson: "clickin on it will do nothing", nope, that's not correct. Clicking on it will take the user to the url of that anchor tag. If the anchor tag happens to be `site.com/vote.php?up=1`, then the visitor/user will be able to click on it, and will be taken to the page, casting a vote.

Comment: @Shef Well of course!  In his example, he doesn't have any URLs, so _IN THIS CONTEXT_ it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".voteUp").click(function(){
    $.post(voteAction({postid: this.id, type: 'up'}), function(data){
        // Replace <span> that's a child of this:
        $('span', this).html(data);
        // Unbind click event from anchor:
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
});
```

If you want to remove the anchor tag instead of unbinding the click event, do:

`$(this).parent().html($(this).html());`

Comment: I should note that removing the tag in the manner above will replace the entire contents of the parent element, so be sure to keep that <a> wrapped in a <span>.